# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException in Spring annotation driven configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-annotations

I am getting the following error when trying to autowire two beans using

> No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] is defined:
>   expected single matching bean but found 2: aConnectionFactory, bConnectionFactory

```
Description:

Parameter 1 of method jmsListenerContainerFactory in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
        - aConnectionFactory: defined by method 'aConnectionFactory' in package.Application
        - bConnectionFactory: defined by method 'bConnectionFactory' in package.Application


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I have this annotation driven configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements
 WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Resource(name = "aConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory aConnectionFactory;

    @Resource(name = "bConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory bConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                    .from(
                        Jms.inboundAdapter(aConnectionFactory)
                                            .destination(aQueue),
                        e -> e.poller( Pollers.fixedRate(100, 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(100))
                     ).channel("entrypoint")
                     .get();
}

   @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsInboundFlowB() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                    .from(
                        Jms.inboundAdapter(bConnectionFactory)
                                            .destination(bQueue),
                        e -> e.poller( Pollers.fixedRate(100, 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(100))
                     ).channel("entrypoint")
                     .get();
}


    @Bean(name = "aConnectionFactory")
    @Profile({"weblogic"})
    public ConnectionFactory aConnectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory factory = null;
        JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
        try {
          factory = (ConnectionFactory) jndi.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error("NamingException for jms/ConnectionFactory", e);
        }

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "bConnectionFactory")
    @Profile({"weblogic"})
    public ConnectionFactory bConnectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory factory = null;
        JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
        try {
          factory = (ConnectionFactory) jndi.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error("NamingException for jms/ConnectionFactory", e);
        }

        return factory;
    }

}
```

Any ideas what's wrong in this code? This seems to be straight forward, but specifying the Qualifier doesn't work, I have also tried to use @Resource. What am I missing there?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: spring confuses between your   @Resource(name = "aConnectionFactory") and  @Bean(name = "aConnectionFactory"). As console suggest you need to mark one them as primary (same for bConnectionFactory )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code.

That is just `JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` from Spring Boot which doesn't like your two `ConnectionFactory` beans, but requires only one.

1. Why just don't follow with that report recommendations and mark one of them with the `@Primary`?
2. Looks like you don't use Spring Boot JMS auto-configuration feature, so that would be just straightforward to disable `JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration

Comment: Thanks Artem, I can't mark any of them as @Primary as I need two of them to be autowired to define two different jmsInboudFlows (from different queues using different connection factories).

Comment: That's correct, but you can use `@Autowired` together with `@Qualifier`. But anyway, I guess, it would be better for you ti disable `JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` since you fully don't use its functionality.

Comment: Note that in order to disable it in the latest versions of Spring Boot, you need to exclude JmsAutoConfiguration as JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration is not public.

Answer (score -1):

The problem consist

javax.jms.ConnectionFactory is singleton, you need one object that type!

**Solutions for your problem:**

- If you need two object that create objects and extend ConnectionFactory
  them change scope as needed.
- try @Scope("singleton") or @Scope("prototype").
- if you receive error, make a objects. then use a scope @Scope("singleton")
- **"Other Two"** disfigure the other class that is already using and setting such an.

Comment: Not sure what you're suggesting - what I need is two singletons of the same type, and as far as I know I can have two singleton beans of the same. What I am looking for is to autowire the correct one.

Comment: that is correct, find that implement interface or class, 
there somewhere in your project, see the wrong is clean. try define scope that @Scope("prototype"), for your two beas

Comment: This does not address the question - the problem is not with scopes here - there is nothing wrong with the code. Please see the accepted answer and the comments below it, which give the correct solution to the question.