# issue with jmsListenerContainerFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solace

I've a Java application in which I need to be able to connect to multiple(3) systems for reading messages from a queue.
I'm using Spring framework in applicationContext file.

I'm getting following runtimeError:

```
"Parameter 1 of method jmsListenerContainerFactory in ... required a single bean, but 3 were found"
```

I tried using scope="prototype" at CachedContainerFactory bean level in the applicationContext file, but no luck.

Not sure how to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your error, but I am able to use multiple connection factories without issues.  Specifically, I use `CachingConnectionFactory` - I'm not aware of any `CachedContainerFactory` as you noted.  Here's an example XML configuration for 2 VPNs:

```
<bean autowire="default" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate" id="v1Template" lazy-init="default">
    <property name="environment">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.naming.provider.url" value="smf://192.168.65.3:55555"/>
            <entry key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory"/>
            <entry key="java.naming.security.principal" value="default@v1"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean autowire="default" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate" id="v2Template" lazy-init="default">
    <property name="environment">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.naming.provider.url" value="smf://192.168.65.3:55555"/>
            <entry key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory"/>
            <entry key="java.naming.security.principal" value="default@v2"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean autowire="default" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" id="v1cf" lazy-init="default">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="v1Template"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="cf"/>
</bean>

<bean autowire="default" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" id="v2cf" lazy-init="default">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="v2Template"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="cf"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory" id="v1ccf">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="v1cf"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory" id="v2ccf">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="v2cf"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

For additional configuration properties (if connecting to Solace using Spring XML configuration), please refer to the [integration guide](https://dev.solace.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Solace-JMS-Integration-with-Spring-v4.0.pdf).

A similar issue was noted in another post - [NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException in Spring annotation driven configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471181/nouniquebeandefinitionexception-in-spring-annotation-driven-configuration).